# discount rows where values are identical within a subset MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing the results of multiple races. It contains columns: *position* (i.e., 1st, 2nd etc.), *ranking* (its ranking in that race), *odds* (given before race) and the *number of racers* in that race.

eg:

```
position  ranking  odds  no_of_runners
--------------------------------------
|   1    |   3   |  2.5 |      6     |
|   2    |   1   |  2   |      6     |
|   3    |   5   |  7   |      6     |
|   4    |   2   |  3.33|      6     |
|   5    |   6   |  12  |      6     |
|   6    |   4   |  3.5 |      6     |
|   1    |   1   |  3   |      6     | <- do not include this because it's a joint favourite
|   2    |   4   |  8   |      6     |
|   3    |   2   |  4   |      6     |
|   4    |   5   |  9   |      6     |
|   5    |   3   |  6.66|      6     | 
|   6    |   1   |  3   |      6     |
```

if I want to know how often the favourite (ranking:1) runner wins I can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM results WHERE position = 1 AND ranking = 1 AND no_of_runners = 6;
```

however, this includes races with joint-favourites (i.e. 2 or more with ranking:1).

I only want to select races where there was a single favourite (i.e., just 1 with ranking:1). is there a way to do this with my table?
Thank you.

Comment: 'however this includes races where there were joint favourites (i.e. 2 or more with ranking:1).' - no it doesn't the position for the 'first' occurance of ranking 1 is 2.. AND what logic is used to discard the indicated row in your sample?

Comment: and you don't have no_of_runners in the table..https://dbfiddle.uk/H45B0dv5

Comment: There is no race identifier in the sample dataset, so we can't tell which row belongs to which race.

Comment: @P.Salmon the logic to discard is based on the fact that within the same race there was another runner with ranking 1 (the last entry on the table)

Comment: There is no first or last in sql tables unless you have another unpublished column which can identify that? AND are you now saying position is not relevant? AND the row you want to discard appears to be the seventh runner in a 6 runner race..

Comment: @P.Salmon so if I hade another column which identified the race, would it be possible to discard races with joint favourites?

Comment: Yes, this is possible (and easy enough).

Comment: Im getting more confused - you started off with a query which identified races where the favourite won, then you wanted to remove a row without a reason and your last comment you want to discard races with joint favourites.